# TypeError: undefined is not a functīon

Tags: angularjs

My controller is calling a method on an injected service, but the method is undefined. If I `console.log` the service from within the controller, it gives an empty object.

Here's the controller:

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.live')
        .controller('LiveController', LiveController);

        LiveController.$inject = ['Hubbub', '$scope'];

        function LiveController(Hubbub, $scope){

            $scope.loading = 1;

            activate();

            function activate() {

                return Hubbub.getDebates().success(function(data){

                    console.log(data);

                }).error(function(data){

                    console.log(data);

                });

            }

        }

})();
```

And the service is defined like this:

```
(function(){

    'use strict';

    angular
        .module('app.api')
        .constant('API_BASE_URL', 'http://localhost/hubbub/public/api/')
        .service('Hubbub', Hubbub);

        Hubbub.$inject = ['$http', 'API_BASE_URL'];

        function Hubbub($http, API_BASE_URL){

            var service = {
                getDebates: getDebates
            };

            return service;


            /* ********************************
            *  Method: getDebates
            ******************************** */
            function getDebates() {

                var request = {
                    method: 'GET',
                    url:    API_BASE_URL + 'debates',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type':     'application/json',
                        'Accept':           'application/json'
                    }
                };

                return $http(request);

            }

        } // function Hubbub
})();
```

Why would it be undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your module dependencies aren't set up correctly, add `app.api` as a dependency.

```
angular.module('app.live',['app.api'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two different angular modules. If you want to use 'Hubbub' service in your angular module module('app.live'), you need to state angular module app.api as a dependency.

```
angular.module('app.live',['app.api']);
```